# How to make clear(empty/without values) spinner on clearbutton

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm using a spinner in my apps so i need a button reset .on click on clearButton button spinner should clear (no value should be displayed )

```
spinner=  (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.mylistspinner);

list= new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("");

list.add("1");        
list.add("2");

adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.custom_spinner_text,list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(urineGlucoseAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnUGItemSelected());
```

Comment: "spinner should clear", does that mean the spinner should reset to the first item, or should all spinner values be cleared?

Comment: Spinner will always show some item from the array of input entries that you are using to fill it up. If  you don't want to show any entry in the spinner you might want to add one value at [0] position with is an empty string "".

Comment: if you are using custom adapter with arrayList. then remove all items from arraylist and call notifydatasetchanged().

Comment: sana/christine ..I have 10 values in my spinner but according to my apps need .i ll hv to add clear button .on click of that it should make clear/or with out valuse like (clear button for date and time)

Answer (score 14):

two way u can do it on click of button use either

```
 arr.clear();
 spinner.setAdapter(null);
```

or

```
 arr.clear();
 spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,arr));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
units = new String[0];
Arrays.fill(units, null);
Log.i("units array length", ""+units.length);
unit_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, units);
spinner.setAdapter(unit_adapter);
// unit_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 2):

on button click do this

```
list.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all spinner items:

```
mySpinner.setAdapter(null);
```

Comment: first remove list items ..list.removeAll(list)

Comment: and then set adapter to spinner again

Answer (score -1):

You can call `adapter.clear();` to remove all items from spinner. Then pass an arraylist again to populate the spinner with new values.